# How can I get the email address in a URL to appear on my webpage with javascript or HTML with a website built on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get the email address from a URL to appear on my webpage with javascript or HTML with a website built on Ruby on Rails?

I have a URL like this:

```
http://dance.danceninjas.com/thanks-so-good?cf_uvid=1ce505f1e32477b73a15a514962e25b2&email=test324@gmail.com
```

And I want to pull the email address from the URL into the webpage so I can say:

> Please verify your email is correct: `<EMAIL_HERE>`

I know that with WordPress I would use the PHP code:

```
echo $_GET["email"];
```

But apparently that won't work with websites built with Ruby on Rails.

I am using ClickFunnels to build my website, which means I have the ability to add Javascript into my footers and add snippets of custom HTML code.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: try `params[:email]`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, **ClickFunnels** acts as a hosting and front-end construction platform that only gives you access to your page only through:

- editing content
- assigning pre-made templates
- placing client-side JavaScript code

There's nothing Rails-specific you can use here. That would imply a lot of potential for security breaches. Execution of arbitrary Ruby can be done right, it's just rarely needed and thus rarely done.

That said, PHP-like solutions such as `$_GET["email"];` won't work by principle. @rorofromfrance's answer has its right sides, but you can't make use of this because you don't own the platform and **you can't modify the templates**. It's **not bad service design**, there are some big advantages of this, the biggest of which is **caching**: a static page without any server-side processing can be placed in cache entirely and served through a CDN that can handle crazy amounts of traffic and stay up.

SO the solution is offloading that action for the client's browser. You pass parameters in a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). This string is accessible through JavaScript (`window.location.search`), in raw format, like:

```
"cf_uvid=1ce505f1e32477b73a15a514962e25b2&email=test324@gmail.com"
```

That said, it should be split into keys and values before being used. And there are plenty of solutions for this [under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). Pick the one you like most.

Comment: This is correct.  You need to use JavaScript.  Clickfunnels has jquery on all pages so you can use a jquery solution if desired as well.

Comment: @Todd you're the cofounder of ClickFunnels, right? I'd hoped that Jquery was included in my ClickFunnels opt-in page, but I don't see it being loaded, and I'm not sure how I can add it myself. Is it within https://www.clickfunnels.com/assets/lander.js? And it should be usable as usual? I wonder why I haven't gotten Jquery to work within my Custom HTML "element". I'm similarly hoping to be able to echo the name and email address of the provided opt-in data (on the thank-you page), perhaps by saving the form data to a cookie or localStorage (I'd prefer not to make it visible in the querystring).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Ruby language (if you can) which then would allow you to access URL parameters like this:

```
params[:email]
```